# How to access value cached using spring @cacheable in other controllers?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching

I have a frequently accessed but bulky value - valueA which is obtained by a method - methodA of rest controller - ControllerA. So I have cached this value using @Cacheable annotation as follows.

```
    @CacheConfig(cacheNames={"abc_cache"})
    public class ControllerA
{

    @Cacheable
    @RequestMapping(value = "/value/" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Value> fetchValue()
    {
       // some logic
       return new ResponseEntity<Value>(value, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I want to access this value in another method - methodB of another controller - controllerB. 
How can I access this value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have some other class/bean to supply that value. Then you can inject that bean in all the controllers that you want.

Something like this:

```
@Component
public class MyValueService {
    @Cacheable
    public Value getValue() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

and then in the controllers

```
public class ControllerA
{
    @Autowired
    private MyValueService valServ;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/value/" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Value> fetchValue()
    {
       return new ResponseEntity<Value>(valServ.getValue(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Are you aware of the Controller -> Service -> Repository pattern?

Basically:

**Controller**s are the web layer. They handle http requests. They use Services.

**Service**s are responsible for the business logic of the application. They use Repositories.

**Repositori**es are responsible for the data access - databases access, read/write from the file system, etc.

You should structure your application that way.

In general I would use caching on the Repository layer. Usually the bottle neck are the I/O operations (read/write to the file system, DB call, calling external service over the network) and that are the things that you want to cache if the possible.

Comment: Thanks Evgenia.. I already have this architecture in my project. Just I was not aware of having cacheable at repository level. In the example you had shown it done on service layer, but from your comment , I think I should do it at dao layer

Comment: Yes, my example was just to illustrate the technique.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should just encapsulate your cacheable logic into a method in another class and then just call it from both controllers.

So

```
public class ControllerA
{

    @Resource
    private Service service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/value/" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<Value> fetchValue()
    {
       // some logic
       Object v = service.cachedMethod();
       return new ResponseEntity<Object>(v, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class Service {

    @Cacheable
    public Object cachedMethod() {... }

}
```